# How do I get this to calculate the gross pay?

Tags: c#

I am having trouble getting the gross pay to output (my method for calculating it is wrong I believe). Any help is appreciated, especially with explanations in layman terms. I am looking more for a solid understanding of why and how it all works.
So far I have the following class (separate from the class with my main method):

```
namespace Project
{
    class Employee
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        private decimal RateOfPay { get; set; }
        public string JobTitle { get; set; }
        public string HireDate { get; set; }

        //constructor
        public Employee (string firstName, string lastName, decimal 
        rateOfPay, string jobTitle, string hireDate)
        {
            FirstName = firstName;
            LastName = lastName;
            RateOfPay = rateOfPay;
            JobTitle = jobTitle;
            HireDate = hireDate;
        }

        public decimal Salary
        {
            //IS THIS HOW I WOULD CALCULATE THE "GROSS"? AS IN WAGE * HOURS?
            get { return RateOfPay; }
            set { RateOfPay = (value * 40);  }

        }
    }
}
```

Then, in the separate class with my main method, I have:

```
namespace EmployeeClass
{
   class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           Employee empl1 = new Employee("Robert", "Smith", (decimal)50.00, 
           "Associate", "5/5/2016");
           Employee empl2 = new Employee("Bill", "Hicks", (decimal)70.00, 
           "Manager", "7/12/2013");

           Console.WriteLine("Employee 1 First Name: {0}", empl1.FirstName);
           Console.WriteLine("Employee 1 Last Name: {0}", empl1.LastName);
           Console.WriteLine("Employee 1 Rate of Pay: {0:C}", empl1.Salary);
           Console.WriteLine("Employee 1 Job Title: {0}", empl1.JobTitle);
           Console.WriteLine("Employee 1 Hire Date: {0}", empl1.HireDate);

           Console.WriteLine("Employee 2 First Name: {0}", empl2.FirstName);
           Console.WriteLine("Employee 2 Last Name: {0}", empl2.LastName);
           Console.WriteLine("Employee 2 Rate of Pay: {0:C}", empl2.Salary);
           Console.WriteLine("Employee 2 Job Title: {0}", empl2.JobTitle);
           Console.WriteLine("Employee 2 Hire Date: {0}", empl2.HireDate);

           Console.ReadLine();
       }
   }
}
```

How would I get the output to show the wages multiplied by the 40 hours?Again, PLEASE USE LAYMAN TERMS! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing the Rate of Pay (which is the amount you earn per hour) with the Gross pay (which is the amount you earn in total).

When you store RateOfPay, you should store and return just the RateOfPay and have a separate function for Salary,which would take a parameter of the number of hours.

```
public decimal Salary(decimal Hours)
    {
        return RateOfPay * Hours;
    }
```